# Whats the most egalitarian way to traverse a binary tree?

Tags: trees, binary

If you wanted to travel down a binary tree in the fairest way possible (not going down one side first then the other) you'd want to use breadth-first search, and it would look something like this:

```
                 1
          2             3
    4       6         5        7
 8   12   10  14    9   13  11   15
```

But as you can see there are smaller numbers on the left and larger ones on the right. It's lopsided. to measure how unfair it is we can sum them per side.

2+4+6+8+12+10+14 = 56

3+5+7+9+13+11+15 = 63

Furthermore, we can explore smaller subtrees and see an even greater divergence by ratio the larger the tree gets:

4+8+12  = 24

5+9+13  = 27

6+10+14 = 30

7+11+15 = 33

Is there a more egalitarian way to traverse the tree? of course, here's an example of a more egalitarian traversal:

```
                    1                   
        2                       3       
   5         7             6           4    
10   15   13    8       9    12     14    11
```

2+5+7+10+15+13+8 = 60

3+6+4+9+12+14+11 = 59

5+10+15 = 30

4+14+11 = 29

7+13+8 =  28

6+9+12 =  27

27 / 30 is less of a divergence then 24 / 33. But who knows if this is the best way to do it? I don't know.

So the question then becomes:

- What is the *most* egalitarian method for traversing the tree?

  Is it a static algorithm? If so does that algorithm hold true no
  matter the size of the tree (how many levels deep)?

  Is there a limit to how fair it can be? you'll notice from the
  example the smallest spread I was able to manually get was 4 on the
  4th level.

One might say the most overall egalitarian way to traverse the tree is to randomly choose spots on each level, but this does not guarantee subtrees to be as egalitarian as they can be.

Intuition suggests that we should be able to find a pattern that gets more and more complex the further it runs. But that doesn't change the initial design of the algorithm depending on how large the tree is.

To explain with examples:

1 levels = "**L, R**", 2 levels = "**L, R** | LL, RR, LR, RL" (the same and them more complex patterns...) [this is what I suspect]

VS

1 levels = "**L, R**", 2 levels = "**R, L** | RL, RR, LL, LR" (whole algorithm changes depending on number of levels...)

But I'd like to know the truth.

Comment: "Traversal" to me suggests that you want each node visited before any of its child nodes. Is that correct? Or would you be interested in any mapping from nodes to numbers?

Comment: Also I notice your example doesn't consider the balanced-ness of the very smallest trees. The 5-10-15 tree has a right side that exceeds the left side by 5, but in the 6-9-12 tree the difference is only 3. Furthermore both 5-10-15 and 7-8-13 with discrepancy 5 are on the left, while better-balanced 6-9-12 and 4-11-14 with discrepancy 5 are on the right. Maybe this doesn't matter to you but you didn't say.

Comment: It seems to me that there are at least two different measures here and it's not clear which is wanted.  Say a tree is $T$, its subtrees are $T_L$ and $T_R$, and the sum of all the nodes in a tree $T$ is $s(T)$.  One thing you might be interested in is $A(T) = |s(T_L) - s(T_R)|$ which is the discrepancy between $T$'s left and right subtrees.  But another thing you might be interested in is $B(T) = |A(T_L) - A(T_R)|$ which is making sure that the left and right subtrees have similar discrepancies in _their_ subtrees. I think there are too many things going on here.

Comment: yes and yes to your above questions. And that's precisely the point: there's a lot going on here, how best to balance these competing requirements? You can think of the constraints in terms of each parent node not wanting to wait any longer than any other parent node waits for their children nodes to be visited. But not just the parent node, but all subsequent parent nodes up the tree.

Comment: To reiterate that point: Basically, as you move down the tree, one level at a time (or should we say one generation at a time) you must choose which node to visit first, second, third and so on until all members of that level are visited before going on to the next level. The order in which you visit them depends on how you visited their parents because you want to equalize as much as possible the amount of time each parent, and every subsequent grandparents have to wait in order to have their children node to get visited.